# How to cross reference an id to another column in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: TableA]

Given the table shown above, what I need to do is if the COUNTRY field for a particular ID is NULL, then pick that corresponding UNDERLYING_ID, and cross-reference it to the ID column and pick the COUNTRY value from the row where the UNDERLYING_ID matches the ID.

So in this case, A701 will have a country value of JAP because the underlying_ID A706 has a match in the ID column (last record)

Not sure how to write the query here. Please advise.

Comment: Hint:  self-`JOIN`.

Comment: can there be multiple levels of having to perform lookups?

Comment: What if `A706` has a NULL country too? Then go after it's `Underlying_ID`? If so, you'll probably want a recursive CTE.

Comment: Very good question JNeveill! So if the Underlying_ID is null as well, then the value would be Null. I'm planning to write a case statement

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.ID, coalesce(t1.country, t2.country) as country
from myTable t1
left join myTable t2 on t1.Id = t2.underlying_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your statement that there doesn't need to be multiple levels of look-ups for a "NULL" country value, I think a sub-select inside a `CASE` statement fits this pattern of data well, and have used it in similar circumstances.

Something like:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN COUNTRY IS NOT NULL THEN COUNTRY
       ELSE ( SELECT T2.COUNTRY FROM [TABLE NAME] T2 WHERE T2.ID = T.UNDERLYING_ID )
       END AS Country
FROM [TABLE NAME] T
```

The engine will very likely convert this to a left join so it performs the same as @Cetin's answer, but in my opinion this is a more readable solution.

If you want to replace the NULL value with a specific value, you can use `COALESCE` for this, like:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(
        CASE WHEN COUNTRY IS NOT NULL THEN COUNTRY
        ELSE ( SELECT T2.COUNTRY FROM [TABLE NAME] T2 WHERE T2.ID = T.UNDERLYING_ID )
        END, 
        '(ReplacementValue)') AS Country
FROM [TABLE NAME] T
```

Comment: How would you add another case statement to insert the value '80' when  T2.ID is NOT equal to T.UNDERLYING_ID??

Comment: so, you want country to be '80' when T.UNDERLYING_ID references an ID that doesn't exist; or when it references one that also has 'NULL'?

Comment: Exactly. I'm guessing that changes the entire structure of the statement. AMIRITE?

Comment: @ProdSupport by 'exactly' do you mean, in both of those cases?

Comment: LOL. I'm sorry, didn't read your question correctly, So the Country value  should be '80' when the original record is null and when it references one also has 'NULL

Comment: @ProdSupport ok, I've added to the answer to show how this can be handled by wrapping the case statement in a coalesce.